# Javascript AJAX XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Im using Javascript to read on a server response and i want to filter the information given by the server so i can style it on my page. The following api call is presented:

```
http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=pulp+fiction&y=&plot=short&r=json
```

And retrieves this information:

```
{"Title":"Pulp Fiction","Year":"1994","Rated":"R","Released":"14 Oct 1994",
 "Runtime":"154 min","Genre":"Crime, Drama","Director":"Quentin Tarantino",
"Writer":"Quentin Tarantino (story), Roger Avary (story), Quentin Tarantino",
"Actors":"Tim Roth, Laura Lovelace, John Travolta, Samuel L. Jackson",...}
```

I need to filter the information from that response to only show the Title and the Runtime information

```
<p id="Title">Movie title!</p>
<p id="Runtime">Movie runtime!</p>
```

The call to the api is:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=pulp+fiction&y=&plot=short&r=json"+str, true);
xhttp.send();
```

I have read lots of things but cant get it to work as i want to, ill apreciate some help! Thanks

Comment: Where is your code? You say you tried lots of things, but couldn't get it to work. But I don't see any evidence that you tried at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    // Step 1 below
    var fullMovie = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    // Step 2 below
    var movie = { title: fullMovie.Title, runtime: fullMovie.Runtime };
    // Step 3 below
    document.getElementById('Title').innerText = movie.title;
    document.getElementById('Runtime').innerText = movie.runtime;
  }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=pulp+fiction&y=&plot=short&r=json', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Running sample: https://jsfiddle.net/mgjyv3q6/1/

Now, "long answer", basically you have to:

1. Parse the `response` or `responseText` as JSON.
2. Create a new object with the desired fields.
3. Render retrieved information in UI.

Also you should consider start using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) or any other library to help you with DOM manipulation and AJAX requests.

Comment: how do i do step 1 and 2?

Comment: @TomasBond You're welcome. Also note I've attached a running sample to help you.

Comment: Yeah! If i want to use the same script in 4 different div tags  where the structure is http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3322364&plot=short&r=json a

Comment: changing the "?i=tt3322364" to the apropiate to the movie, how can i load over the same script different url?

Comment: @TomasBond you have to dynamically change the requested URL. I've updated the running sample: https://jsfiddle.net/mgjyv3q6/1/

Comment: I have updated your jsfiddle, so it adapts to my needs. i have two diffent div tags with an ID with the IMDB movie ID of the film. I need the script to run and load the two movies data... https://jsfiddle.net/mgjyv3q6/5/